# Prevent newline after clist_map_inline

Tags: latex3

I'm trying to automate the creation of some forms, and part of that
effort is automatically creating the correct number of blank rows in a
table-like form. That's led me to the following strange behavior:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \clistMap \clist_map_inline:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|ll|}
\clistMap{one, two, three}{#1 &\\\hline}
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|ll|}
one &\\\hline
two &\\\hline
three &\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The two tables are typeset differently. I don't understand why.
There's a trailing row after the three rows in the first table. I say
a trailing row, because this following table is typeset the same as
the first.

```
\begin{tabular}{|ll|}
    one &\\\hline
    two &\\\hline
    three &\\\hline
    \\
\end{tabular}
```

As one final pair of examples, as minimal as possible, note the same
appearance of the following two tables:

```
\begin{tabular}{|ll|}
    \clistMap{}{#1 &\\\hline}
\end{tabular}

\medskip % So you can see where one table ends and the other begins.

\begin{tabular}{|ll|}
    \\
\end{tabular}
```

How do I get rid of this trailing newline? For bonus points---If you'd
be so kind, future answerers of mine---how would one detect that some
other unexpected control sequences are there? I tried using fancyvrb
commands to do it, and I could never quite get what I wanted; I wasn't
able to detect the `\\` control sequence, and other characters like
`&` caused problems. I also tried using the trace package, something
like `\clistMap` expands to around 1000 lines of expanded macros.

Comment: If you use `\clist_map_function:nN` instead it works (don't ask me why, though :)

Comment: `form` doesn't appear to be a generally available class, I think your example would also work with `article` can you edit so people can test?

Comment: you do not have an extra `\\ ` to see the effect just use `\relax` or `{}` or `\ ` or more or less anything at all after the final `\hline`  in your second table.

Comment: `\clist_map_inline:nn` is not expandable and will leave something behind the last \hline which create a new line.

Comment: Wow. You guys move fast. Edited. Though... it's a little late for that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't quite understand what you mean. I wrote `\clistMap{}{#1 &\\\hline}\relax` in my test file, and I still see the extra row in the table. What was I supposed to see, exactly?

Comment: @Beelzebielsk Not this one. The one which you create the table by hand :)

Comment: in your first code block you have  two tables which have different output, the first has a extra spurious row, but that is not because the l3 code generated an extra `\\ `, add `\relax` before `\end{tabular}` to the second tabular then the two will produce the same output.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see. Okay. If you'd be so kind, I'm going to combine something that @egreg said in his answer with what you said, to double-check my understanding (where he said "However it also has to cover its tracks ... stepped down at the end.") If I write `\begin{tabular}{|ll|} \refstepcounter{somecounter} \end{tabular}`, then I notice a new row is started. Is that roughly what's going on when `\clist_map_function:nN` finishes?

Comment: @Beelzebielsk yes _anything_ in that position will start a cell and so a row, an assignment like `\refstepcounter` or just `\relax` (which does nothing) the only things in that position that do not start a new row have to expand to nothing, like `\@empty`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `\clist_map_function:nN`, defining a temporary function:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\clistMap}{mm}
 {
  \cs_gset:Nn \__beelzebielsk_map:n { #2 }
  \clist_map_function:nN { #1 } \__beelzebielsk_map:n
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
\clistMap{one, two, three}{#1 &\\\hline}
\end{tabular}
\qquad
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
one &\\\hline
two &\\\hline
three &\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The problem with `\clist_map_inline:nn` is that it leaves TeX in the state where a new cell has already been started when it realizes that the loop has ended.

[image]

This is actually what `\clist_map_inline:nn` does: it defines a new “unnamed” function and does `\clist_map_function:nN` with it. However it also has to cover its tracks, particularly for being usable also nested, and for this it uses a counter that has to be stepped down at the end: this is the operation that creates the unwanted additional row.

More explicitly: `\clist_map_inline:nn { <clist> } { <code> }` roughly does

```
\int_incr:Nn \<reserved>_int
\cs_gset:cn { <reserved> \int_eval:n \<reserved>_int :n } { <code> }
\clist_map_function:nc { <clist> } { <reserved> \int_eval:n \<reserved>_int :n }
\int_decr:Nn \<reserved>_int
```

The function passed to `\clist_map_function:nc` so depends on the nesting level, because the reserved counter is associated to clist mappings. This allows `\clist_map_inline:nn` to contain in its second argument an inner `\clist_map_inline:nn`, which will execute `\clist_map_function:nc` with a *different* function.

However, the `\int_decr:Nn \<reserved>_int` operation will trigger, in your case, TeX starting a new cell. TeX tables are always rebellious beasts. `;-)`.

With the proposed definition, the operations on counters are skipped; of course you cannot nest `\clistMap` in `\clistMap`.

Comment: Could you explain why there's this difference between `\clist_map_function:nN` and `\clist_map_inline:nn`? There's nothing obvious to me about why one would have to leave a little extra stuff after the loop and the other doesn't. A reference for my familiarity: I've used TeX for several years, and I've read a few chapters of the TeXBook. I still find TeX and all related things extremely obtuse (once I want to start creating things of my own). Overall, not that familiar with the internals, TeX primitives, nor with Latex3.

Comment: @Beelzebielsk I added some more explanations

Comment: It is an interesting question if that could be avoided somehow in the inline versions (I guess that is the same with all other functions of that nature too). If not it might be something that is worth documenting

Comment: @FrankMittelbach I'm curious as to how you'd document this. I doubt you'd just say, "Careful using it with tables!" since I get the feeling that this detail could affect the display of other things. However, if you just said something more general to the effect of "the inline variant leaves stuff after the last iteration", I wouldn't understand that this could affect table typesetting. I struggle with TeX and LaTeX because the connections between various things is not obvious, and I stumble haphazardly onto those connections by reading books and random stackexchange posts.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach To say this another way, if the documentation already said, "The inline variants leave other stuff after the last iteration," I'd have still posted this question.

Comment: @Beelzebielsk documentation would mean to explicitly say that if used it would start a cell in an halign construct. But agreed, that area is far from obvious for many programmer, e.g., that something simple as \relax will do that to you and it is not clear how to best describe that.

Answer (score 3):

I am sure everyone will forgive my somewhat off-topic answer, and this is just to provide an example illustrating @egreg explanations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xinttools}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|ll|}
\hline
\xintFor #1 in {one, two, three}:
{#1 &\\\hline}
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{|ll|}
\hline
one &\\\hline
two &\\\hline
three &\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Although `\xintFor` acts non-expandably, it is careful not to do anything "non vanishing by pure expansion" **at its end**. This allows it to not trigger accidentally a new row. This constraint does however have some limitation effect on the features of `\xintFor` (see the boxed "15.17 \xintifForFirst, \xintifForLast" comments in xint.pdf).

Notice that the `\xintFor` nests well.

A side remark here is about the strange "gaps" one sees (when magnifying) at the joining of horizontal and vertical lines in both (identical) tabulars: add `\usepackage{array}`  to fix that.

Comment: It's actually not that off-topic. The main goal of this question was to automate the creation of tabular-style forms. This is another method toward that approach. Though, I'm preferring the LaTeX3 stuff.

Answer (score 3):

You could make the original function safe in this position by use of `\noalign`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \clistMap \clist_map_inline:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|ll|}
\noalign\bgroup\clistMap{one, two, three}{\egroup#1 &\\\hline\noalign\bgroup}\egroup
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|ll|}
one &\\\hline
two &\\\hline
three &\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, I noticed that, I was not referring to the actual item being scoped but only to the additional dealings of `\clist_map_inline:nn` in-between (if any) and after the last iteration.

Comment: @jfbu ah OK I'd have to check what it's really doing (or you could ask Joseph in chat:-)